# Извлечение слов из текста Python

Tags: python-3.x

Как выделить слова в строке, разделяя их по любым символам кроме букв?
Пример:
whatever.wherever1solution;solutional
Должны получиться cлова whatever, wherever, solution, solutional

Comment: `re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+', текст)`

Comment: @andreymal По пробелам тоже должно

Comment: Этот вариант и по пробелам вполне разделяет

Comment: У меня текст не разделяет, выводи пустой список

Comment: У меня разделяет, вы что-то делаете не так

Comment: Если вдруг у вас буквы неанглийские, а вы об этом постеснялись нам рассказать, то `re.findall(r'\w+', текст)`

Comment: @andreymal Да, извините, об этом не сказал. Спасибо